# In Tensorflow what is difference between Aligned and not Aligned in Tensor class?

Tags: tensorflow, eigen

Hi I'm strongly interested in framework Tensorflow, so I studied about it. However I got some question about Tensor class. There is normal `Tensor` class (which is `Eigen::TensorMap<Eigen::Tensor<T, NDIMS, Eigen::RowMajor, IndexType>, Eigen::Aligned>`) and `UnalignedTensor` class which does not have Eigen::Aligned.

I want to know the difference between two tensor type with specific example. It could be trivial question but I want to know exact meaning of Eigen::Aligned.

Thanks.

Comment: It is a short question but a good answer requires to talk about alignment in depth. A good starting point is reading about SIMD, SSE in CPUs with alignment. Be aware any potential 3-sentence-answer here would be not be able to cover a good explanation.

Comment: Thanks for good advice. I will check out from SSE in CPUs with alignment. ;>

Comment: A bit late, but it was a rather useless comment at best, quite a bit misleading at worst. I'd point you to the Eigen doc for some info on alignment in Eigen: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__DenseMatrixManipulation__Alignement.html